# Where do I put the css I want to use in a module?

Tags: html, css, module, dotnetnuke

I building my very first DotNetNuke site and now I have a page where I have to put a HTML module.

I need to format the text in it, but was told to create CSS classes.
My question is, where do I put .css files in my DNN site, how do I access it, do I have to use .css files that already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For styles that aren't associated with any particular module, you will probably want to put them in the site stylesheet, which can be edited through the Site Settings module.

If you want these styles to apply to multiple portals/sites within the same DNN installation, you may prefer to make changes to the skin's `skin.css` file.  However, if you choose to make changes here, you won't be able to apply updates to the skin (if it's developed by an external developer) without overwriting your changes.

Answer (score 1):

if the style you want is for the skin you have to name it style.css but if you are talking about module name it module.css

Answer (score 0):

A css file that is linked to as 'href="style.css"' would be a file called style.css within the same folder structure as the .html page.